# Has anyone managed to write a fluent version of adding the Castle NHibernate Facility?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor, windsor-nhfacility

Has anyone managed to do this?

Basically I am looking for the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <facilities>
    <facility id="nhibernate"
                isWeb="false"
                type="Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility, Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration"
        configurationBuilder="FS.SUV.Services.FluentNHibernateConfigBuilder, FS.SUV.Services">
      <factory id="nhibernate.factory">
        <settings>
          <item key="show_sql">false</item>
          <item key="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</item>
          <item key="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</item>
          <item key="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</item>          
          <item key="connection.connection_string_name">DBConnection</item>
          <item key="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory , NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</item>
        </settings>
      </factory>
    </facility>       
  </facilities> 
</configuration>
```

And the corresponding code to install this would be

```
 container
   .Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromXmlFile("Windsor.config"))
```

Where Windsor.config is the xml above.

In a fluent form

Typyically you can do stuff like

```
             .AddFacility<NHibernateFacility>("NHibernate", cfg=>cfg.FacilityConfig)
```

However from the options in Intellisense it is unclear if anything will provide what I want from the xml snippet above.

I have done some searches which have returned the following which either do not work or refer to a previous version. I am using NHibernate 2 for this one project with Castle.

[Tuna Toksoz post](http://tunatoksoz.com/post/Fluent-Interface-for-NH-Facility-e28093-Take-1.aspx)

But with no joy. Can anyone help! I know, I know I could always use a different IOC! But I am curious if anyone else has come across this issue. I can also just leave it as xml but I prefer the fluent configuration because I can then dynamically set connections strings and other factory properties at will.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a fluent NHibernate Facility at https://github.com/haf/Castle.Facilities.NHibernate.

You configure it using FluentNHibernate and then you can have session-per-transaction, session-per-web request or session-transient lifestyles.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, nobody finished implementing the fluent interface. It certainly isn't present in the [code repository](http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration). Which gives *you* the opportunity to implement it and contribute it to the project! Get in touch with Tuna if you're up for it.

Otherwise, remember that Windsor configuration *can* be built programmatically. It might not be as pretty as a fluent interface, but it's not XML either. [Here's an example](http://osdir.com/ml/nhusers/2010-04/msg00518.html) of the NHibernate facility being configured programmatically.

Comment: Sounds like fun. You're right its not pretty I'll have a look at it.

Comment: https://castle.uservoice.com/forums/16605-official-castle-project-feedback-forum/suggestions/867983-configure-nhibernatefacility-using-nhibernate-conf?ref=title